# how to understand yarn appattempt log and diagnostics?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a spark application on YARN cluster(on AWS EMR). The application seems to be killed and I want to find the cause. I try to understand the YARN info given in the following screen. [image]
The diagnostic line in the screen seems to show that YARN killing the app because of the memory limit:

`Diagnostics: Container [pid=1540,containerID=container_1488651686158_0012_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.6 GB of 1.4 GB physical memory used; 3.6 GB of 6.9 GB virtual memory used. Killing container`.

However, the appattempt log shows completely different exception, something related to the IO/network. My question is : should I trust the diagnostic in the screen or the appattempt log? Is the IO exception causing the kill or the out of memory cause the IO exception in the appattempt log? Is it another log/diagnostic I should look at? Thanks.

```
17/03/04 21:59:02 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread task-result-getter-0
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:579)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "task-result-getter-0" java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1148)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:579)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        ... 2 more
17/03/04 21:59:02 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/03/04 21:59:02 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from ip-172-31-9-207.ec2.internal/172.31.9.207:38437 is closed
17/03/04 21:59:02 INFO RetryingBlockFetcher: Retrying fetch (1/3) for 1 outstanding blocks after 5000 ms
17/03/04 21:59:02 ERROR DiskBlockManager: Exception while deleting local spark dir: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1488651686158_0012/blockmgr-941a13d8-1b31-4347-bdec-180125b6f4ca
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1488651686158_0012/blockmgr-941a13d8-1b31-4347-bdec-180125b6f4ca
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:1010)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$storage$DiskBlockManager$$doStop$1.apply(DiskBlockManager.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$storage$DiskBlockManager$$doStop$1.apply(DiskBlockManager.scala:165)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$DiskBlockManager$$doStop(DiskBlockManager.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.stop(DiskBlockManager.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1361)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$11.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1842)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1841)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
17/03/04 21:59:02 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/03/04 21:59:02 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/03/04 21:59:02 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/03/04 21:59:02 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/03/04 21:59:02 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Thread-3
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:176)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:138)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.isSymlink(Utils.scala:1021)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$11.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1842)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1841)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
17/03/04 21:59:02 WARN ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '$anon$2' failed, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:176)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:138)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.isSymlink(Utils.scala:1021)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$11.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1842)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1841)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

The container was killed (memory exceeds physical memory limits) so any attempt to reach this container fails.

Yarn is fine to have an overall view of the process, but you should prefer spark history server to analyse better your job (check unbalanced memory in spark history).

[image: a well balanced memory stage]

Comment: I don't see any log message containing "unbalanced memory". What string should I search in the log to monitor unbalanced memory ?

Comment: That's not a current output, I was refering to spark history. You should go down each job / stage (when it fails) and check if one particular executor / task receives all the data.

Answer (score 0):

The information in your screenshot is the most relevant.  Your ApplicationMaster container ran out of memory.  You need to increase `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb` which is set in mapred-site.xml.  I recommend a value of 2000 since that will usually accommodate running Spark and MapReduce applications at scale.

Comment: AWS-EMR set yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb to 2880 by default. I tried to set it to even larger value of 7000, still failed.

Comment: What is your spark.driver.memory set to?